# How to override amount in PayPal hosted button (recurring payments)

Tags: php, paypal

I have a client that uses paypal to capture recurring payments.  Their previous developer set up a hosted button for each subscription type which is chosen by the user from a series of 3 dropdown menus.  There are 3 different subscription lengths each with their own dropdown menus with multiple selections, however when sent to paypal, it's literally only 3 different payment amounts.  Why a hosted button was setup for EACH POSSIBLE combo is beyond me, but it's what I have to work with.

**My problem** is now the client wants to accept coupons/discounts and wants the price subtracted before the user sees it on paypal.  This is easy enough to do dynamically (they will have multiple coupon campaigns going at once), IF I were generating the button code, however all I have to work with is a string:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=2FSZJAH95MJL4
```

or similar... 126 of them to be exact.  I've tried simply passing the new amount over in the query string, but it's ignored.

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=2FSZJAH95MJL4&amount=9.99
```

I don't mean to be dense and this is my first time posting, but I'd like to know the answer to this one.  How do I send a new amount over to paypal with hosted buttons like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to update/change the amount in hosted buttons dynamically, you will need to login to www.paypal.com to update the hosted button information or make use of [API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMUpdateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) to update the hosted button.
To overcome this you may need to use Clear text buttons(which is not hosted).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. By 'make use of the API' are you referring to changing the price for the subscription (recurring payment), process the payment, then change it back?

Comment: Yes, update the price via API call. But, am not sure why do you want to change it back.If you want to update the price for a specific peroid of time, then yes, you need to change it back.

Comment: Yes, there are set prices for all 3 subscriptions, but the client wants to accept 'coupons' whereby lowering the price of a sub based on a successful entry.  I only need to override the price of the sub for that instance. Using the API would allow any would be user signing up at the same time to get the discount price, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more hidden field for amount

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try instead of buttons, do this:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

Read more [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside)

Comment: question was how to update the hosted button.
your answer is using a clear text button to overcome this which does not actually answer the problem

Comment: can you tell me why it is absurd?

Comment: Thank you for the answer reply @Evgeny. However, I do understand how to make the form data and send it over to paypal just fine in a normal way (clear buttons). I'm sorry for not specifying that in my question. In this problem, there are 126 hosted buttons that I need to be able to modify the amount variable dynamically.  I agree, in a normal circumstance the logic is replaced very very easily like you've stated, just not this case :(.